# Datetime module in python

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, theory

I have a theorical question about the two following codes. The first one works and the second does not.

```
import datetime 

c = datetime.datetime.now()
print(c.day, c.month, c.year)
```

```
class X: 

    def __init__(self, n,c):
        self.name = n
        self.color = c 

    def initiator(self,n ,c ):
        self.__init__(n, c)
        return self.name, self.color

o = X()
r = o.initiator("John","yellow")
print(r.name, r.color)
```

I would like to know why I can't assign the return of the function in the variable r in the second code, just like I think it was done in the first code. Is there a way I could do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way python creates a class

The following works.

```
class X: 
    def __init__(self, n,c):
        self.name = n
        self.color = c 

    def get_name_and_color(self): # initiator shadows the init function as a name
        return self.name, self.color

o = X("John","yellow")
r_name, r_color = o.get_name_and_color()
print(r_name, r_color)
```

Notice how we use the parameters when creating the class.
Also it's good to know you can return more values comma separated. This way you can directly use them by the correct name.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! 
My whole point is to actually understand how the datetime package works.
I didn't know about this multiple return, nice!

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed the point of your question, but it seems to me that you are trying to set up method `initiator` as a custom constructor. Why? The class name is already the constructor.

```
o = X("John", "yellow")
print(o.name, o.color)     # John yellow
```

Python deliberately does not offer an obvious way to define multiple constructors.

Your analogy with `datetime.datetime.now()` is not to the point. `now()` is not a constructor: it is a class method that returns an instance. You can get the same effect like this:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, n, c):
        self.name = n
        self.color = c

    @classmethod
    def initiator(cls, n ,c ):
        return = cls(n, c) # return a class instance

r = X.initiator("John", "yellow")
print(r.name, r.color)     # John yellow
```

With this contrived example it is hard to see why you would want to do that, but on the analogy of `datetime.datetime.now()` that is nondeterministic or not "pure" because its result does not depend solely on the input parameters, you can add this to class X:

```
    @classmethod
    def me(cls):
        return cls(os.environ["USERNAME"], os.environ["COMPUTERNAME"])
```

and then

```
r = X.me()
print(r.name, r.color)     # JoaoPedroMatias SOMEAWESOMEBOX
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! 
My whole point is to actually understand how the datetime package works, and it was messing me, but I got it better. I'll try to find out the code of this package.

Comment: If you are wondering why `now()` is a class method of `datetime.datetime` and not a module function of `datetime` you would not be the first.